# Celery/django - chunk tasks

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a lot of tasks that are being generated that I would like to group in to chunks, but I think in the opposite way as Celery does. From my understanding, I can use the chunks feature to split up a list of items when I create the task.

I would like to do the opposite. The data I have is being produced one at a time from different endpoints. But I would like to process them in chunks so that I can insert them in to a database in single transactions.

So essentially I'd like to add items to a queue 1 at a time, and dequeue them 100 at a time (either at some specified time interval or once the queue reaches a certain level) and use a transaction to insert all of them in to a database. This would save me from Is this possible with celery? Would it be easier to drop down to redis and create a custom queue there?

Comment: i think using redis for a temporary queue would be better, you can use the queue from redis to run a single task on celery